# Hungarian Algorithm

Tags: hungarian-algorithm

I have found an implementation of Hungarian Algorithm, but I have a question about the meaning of "starred zero" and "primed zero". I think this is used to refer to a marked zero, but I am not sure. Is it correct?

This is the code: http://ccp.uchicago.edu/khetarpal/code/edit-distance/HungarianAlgorithm.java

Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with hungarian notation?

Comment: Read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm zero prime looks like a standard naming in this algorithm

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 4):

As you should know the Hungarian (or Kuhn–Munkres) algorithm is a combinatorial optimization algorithm that solves the assignment problem. It consists of a set of operations applied to a square matrix whose cells values are a function of the cost of assigning the "task" i to the "worker" j or the "worker" i to the "task" j. Being i and j the row and column numbers respectively.
Here I include a brief description of the implementation you're using so you can realize what's the objective of starring and priming cells (or zeroes).

**Step 0**: Create a matrix called the cost matrix in which each element represents the cost of assigning one of the workers to one of jobs. Go to ***Step 1***

**Step 1** (*reduceMatrix*): For each row, find the smallest element and subtract it from every element in its row. Go to ***Step 2***.

**Step 2** (*initStars*): Find a zero (Z) in the resulting matrix. If there is no starred zero in its row or column, star Z. Repeat for each element in the matrix. Go to ***Step 3***.

**Step 3** (*coverColumnsOfStarredZeroes*): Cover each column containing a starred zero. If K columns are covered, the starred zeros describe a complete set of unique assignments. In this case, Go to ***DONE***, otherwise, Go to ***Step 4***.

**Step 4** (*primeSomeUncoveredZero*): Find a noncovered zero and prime it. If there is no starred zero in the row containing this primed zero, Go to ***Step 5***. Otherwise, cover this row and uncover the column containing the starred zero. Continue in this manner until there are no uncovered zeros left. Save the smallest uncovered value and Go to ***Step 6***.

**Step 5** (*incrementSetOfStarredZeroes*): Construct a series of alternating primed and starred zeros as follows.  Let Z0 represent the uncovered primed zero found in Step 4.  Let Z1 denote the starred zero in the column of Z0 (if any). Let Z2 denote the primed zero in the row of Z1 (there will always be one). Continue until the series terminates at a primed zero that has no starred zero in its column. Unstar each starred zero of the series, star each primed zero of the series, erase all primes and uncover every line in the matrix. Return to ***Step 3***.

**Step 6** (*makeMoreZeroes*): Add the value found in Step 4 to every element of each covered row, and subtract it from every element of each uncovered column.  Return to ***Step 4*** without altering any stars, primes, or covered lines.

**DONE**: Assignment pairs are indicated by the positions of the starred zeros in the cost matrix.  If C(i,j) is a starred zero, then the element associated with row i is assigned to the element associated with column j.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On Step 4, do you restart the search for uncovered Zeros from the beginning? Or are now-uncovered elements on past columns unimportant?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out the answer. For future readers: no, if you're looping correctly (row outer, column inner).